# ReactJS: Building Custom Camera Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im trying to write a custom camera component inside my ReactJS component because i cant seem to find any npm library that really fits my requirement. So i found this article https://frontendnews.io/editions/2018-08-15-simple-camera-component that gives a pretty good details. But i think im having trouble in changing these pure javascript code into React component. I cant seem to render the Camera component inside my page. Plase take a look at my code and see what i did wrong.

Here's my Camera component:

```
import {Component} from 'react'

class Camera extends Component {
  connectedCallback() {
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.videoElement = document.createElement('video');
    this.canvasElement = document.createElemnt('canvas');
    this.videoElement.setAttribute('playsinline', true);
    this.canvasElement.style.display = 'none';
    shadow.appendChild(this.videoElement);
    shadow.appendChild(this.canvasElement);
  }

  open(constraints) {
  return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((mediaStream) => {
      // Assign the MediaStream!
      this.videoElement.srcObject = mediaStream;
      // Play the stream when loaded!
      this.videoElement.onloadedmetadata = (e) => {
        this.videoElement.play();
      };
    });
}
}

export default Camera
```

Here's my cam.js where i render the camera component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Camera from '../elements/camera';
import ElemLayout from '../elements/layout';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
  }

  async function() {
    const camera = document.querySelector('Camera');
    camera != null && await camera.open({ video: { facingMode: 'user' }})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ElemLayout routes={ this.props.routes } isLoading={this.state.isLoading} >
        <Camera />
      </ElemLayout>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I notice, you're extending React.Component, but you're missing a call to `render()`

When you use a Class component, a call to the `render()` lifecycle method is REQUIRED. Here is some more info on React Components:

[React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

When I click the link to the article, I notice that they're making use of web components. You actually don't really need to make any changes to that tutorial's code.

You can use web components in React, see this page in the React docs:

[React & Web Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html)